# Como selecionar um elemento que depende de outro por XPath

Tags: xpath

Preciso construir um `xpath` que retorne o `Meu elemento` apenas se a `Dependencia`estiver presente na tela.

Atualmente estou fazendo o filtro do `Meu elemento` utilizando o trecho abaixo:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Meu elemento')]
```

---

```html
...
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a>Dependencia</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <div>Meu elemento</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui solucionar meu problema com o seguinte xpath:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Meu elemento')][//*[contains(text(), 'Dependencia')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a estrutura do XML que você incluiu acima, o XPath abaixo seleciona o conteúdo do `div` dentro de outro `div` que é precedido imediatamente por um `div` contendo uma `table` que possua uma célula contendo um `a` com o conteúdo exato 'Dependencia':

```
//div/div[preceding::div/table//a[text() = 'Dependencia']]
```

Isto funciona para a subestrutura que você incluiu acima. Se não funcionar você deve incluir mais detalhes do seu HTML/XML (tags omitidos, namespaces, etc.)

Comment: Da forma que citou, qualquer estrutura que fosse alterada no XML resultaria em perca do resultado final. Me pareceu uma boa solução, porém hard coded.